# best way to install emacs auto-complete mode

Tags: emacs

I want to install the autocomplete-mode for emacs.

When I searched through the repos (marmalade etc) I found the following packages ac-dabbrev and ac-ja. On googling ac-dabbrev, it seems to be last updated in 2009 -

> http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ac-dabbrev.el

On the instructions for installing auto complete mode, in emacs wiki, it leads to a download link -

> http://cx4a.org/pub/auto-complete/auto-complete-1.3.1.zip

How should I install the autocomplete mode through the package ac-dabbrev or by dowloading it from the above link ? Or is there an updated package ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: Which Linux distribution do you use? If you use Gentoo, there is `app-emacs/auto-complete`. I think there is similar package in other distribution.

Comment: I tried the second way before.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All fresh Emacses are coming with `package.el` that simplifies installation of 3rd party packages.  `auto-complete` and `ac-dabbrev` are available from M[ELPA package repository](http://melpa.milkbox.net/). Read [install instructions](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#installing) on MELPA site, or about [`package.el`/ELPA](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA) in more details

Comment: Thanks it was the auto-complete package I was looking. I had confused it with the ac-dabbrev package.